# Mac snow leopard: ruby version kept coming back to 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-1.9

I installed ruby 1.9.2 and checked with ruby -v and it was fine (1.9.2) but after I restarted my computer after terminal somehow stopped responding, ruby switched back to 1.8.7. This has happened before and I ended up re-intalling.

Do you know what might have happened?

Thank you so much!

Cheers,
eFan

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ which ruby
```

And:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

I bet you installed ruby in `/usr/local/ruby/bin/ruby` but are running the one in `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Comment: The first will tell you which executable is being found when you type `ruby --version` or `ruby myfile.rb`; the second will show you the directories that are searched to find executables (and the order in which they are searched).

Comment: dhcp:~ efan1030$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

dhcp:~ efan1030$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: @efan1030 It means that you need to follow the advice from my answer, and modify your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` comes _before_ any other entries. It means that, as suspected, you're using Ruby 1.8.7 that came installed with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you edited your `PATH` variable in that one Terminal session, but not for all future sessions. Assuming that you have a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to the correct install, you need to modify your `PATH` to look in `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Create or edit a file named `.profile` in your home directory with this line in it:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ curl -L http://get.rvm.io | bash 
$ rvm install 1.9.2  
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

Comment: This 'answer' is suggesting that you use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) instead to install and manage multiple Ruby installs. The sparse details do not cover the install procedures which you are instructed to follow after the first step. Despite the current community fondness for rvm, I do not personally advocate it. (Downvoted due to incomplete details or description of what this will do to the user's system.)

Comment: RVM is a very solid, well tested and well supported tool for handling Ruby installations. I use it on several Linux boxes and two Macs. It's worked great, and is the first thing added when I set up a new system for my Ruby development. [RVM installation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) is easy. The "Post Install" requires one line added to your shell startup script to manage the path. Use `rvm use 1.9.2` or whatever version to switch to that RVM managed version. `Add --default` to default to it. RVM puts everything in `~/.rvm`. No more `sudo`! Highly recommended.

Comment: @Greg I disagree. I've not once used RVM without a major problem. From random deletion of all gems to completely destroying a Ruby install so badly it couldn't even run "ruby -v" without crashing. I wish RVM did work as advertised but right now it's just too fragile and I don't like spending an hour installing everything only to have RVM destroy it in 10 seconds. Worst off the backup feature for saving a configuration is useless as it doesn't actually allow you to restore but only gives you a false sense of security until you try to use it. I'm sorry to be so harsh but RVM is bad, really bad.

Comment: What I find much easier, and safer, is to manually install each version using Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and then I use a bash script to create sym links for the version I want to use. Changing version is then as simple as typing "ruby192" or "ruby187".

Comment: @Mike Bethany, I've had completely opposite results using it on a couple different Linuxes plus my Mac OS boxes.

Comment: @Kalyan Except I know what I'm doing and I've had nothing but problems therefore your ad hominem assertion is wrong. In fact I found it quite easy to go wrong with RVM. All you have to do is install it, install a few versions of Ruby, install some gems, switch between versions a few times, and BAM! It's broken... again. @Greg Many people have no problems but many people have lots of problems. Since I'm one that has had numerous, catastrophic problems I chose not to use it. It can't hurt to try it but it needs to be said that it's very flakey and can cause you a lot of grief.